# Smooth vertical tabbed navigation in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, navigation

I want a smooth transitioned vertical tabbed navigation like [this](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/animated-vertical-tabbed-navigation-with-pure-css3/) with pure js solution.

I have tried something but its not as smooth and doesn't take the content to be scrolled to the top of the div.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error cupiditate veritatis laudantium possimus quia nulla ut accusantium, dolores consectetur tempora officiis nemo similique voluptates nostrum architecto, quas qui iste sapiente.

```
<div class="wrapper">

        <div id="left">
                <a class="links_" href="#one_">tab 1</a>
                <a class="links_" href="#two_">tab 2</a>
                <a class="links_" href="#three_">tab 3</a>
                <a class="links_" href="#four_">tab 4</a>
                <a class="links_" href="#five_">tab 5</a>
        </div>
        <div id="main" class="main">
            <div class="ctr" id="one_">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate tenetur earum voluptate iste maxime in quod deleniti, omnis ipsam corporis atque veritatis facilis fugiat quisquam? Illum odit ratione, recusandae doloremque.</div>
            <div class="ctr" id="two_">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div><div class="ctr" id="three_">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div><div class="ctr" id="four_">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div><div class="ctr" id="five_">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    (function() {

            var d = document;
            var getId = function(id) { return d.getElementById(id); };
            var getClass = function(cl) { return d.getElementsByClassName(cl); };

            var link_ = getId("left"), first_ = getId("first"), main_ = getClass('ctr'), mid_= getId("main"), a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                // console.log(a);
                for(var i=0; i<=a.length;i++){
                console.log(a[i]);
                a.onclick = function(){
                    var href = this.getAttribute("href");
                    href = href.replace("#","");
                    d.getId(href).scrollTop = mid_.offsetTop+first_.offsetHeight;

                };

                }
                })();


    </script>
```

It's taking the whole page to the top because i've used hyperlinks may be. Any solution?

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77Lhbomb/)**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  // addEvent wraper for crossbroswer 
  // you can use this as addEvent(element,"click"||"mouseover"||"mouseout",callbackfunction);
  if (typeof addEventListener !== "undefined") {
    addEvent = function(obj, evt, fn) {
      obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    };

    removeEvent = function(obj, evt, fn) {
      obj.removeEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    };
  } else if (typeof attachEvent !== "undefined") {
    addEvent = function(obj, evt, fn) {
      var fnHash = "e_" + evt + fn;

      obj[fnHash] = function() {
        var type = event.type,
          relatedTarget = null;

        if (type === "mouseover" || type === "mouseout") {
          relatedTarget = (type === "mouseover") ? event.fromElement : event.toElement;
        }

        fn.call(obj, {
          target: event.srcElement,
          type: type,
          relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
          _event: event,
          preventDefault: function() {
            this._event.returnValue = false;
          },
          stopPropagation: function() {
            this._event.cancelBubble = true;
          }
        });
      };

      obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, obj[fnHash]);
    };
  }

  // this is magical animateScroll function which take first paramter as a document element
  // second parameter as time in milisecond 
  // third as a callbackfunction when animation is completed
  function animateScroll(elem, time, callbackfunction) {
    if (!elem) return;
    var to = elem.offsetTop;
    var from = window.scrollY;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
      timer = setInterval(function() {
        var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
        window.scrollTo(0, (from + step * (to - from)) + 1);
        if (step == 1) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          callbackfunction();
        };
      }, 25);
    window.scrollTo(0, (from + 1));
  }

  var d = document;
  var getId = function(id) {
    return d.getElementById(id);
  };
  var getClass = function(cl) {
    return d.getElementsByClassName(cl);
  };
  //temp array will use this to change URL and document element from the DOM
  var ar = ["one_", "two_", "three_", "four_", "five_"];
  var link_ = getId("left"),
    first_ = getId("first"),
    main_ = getClass('ctr'),
    mid_ = getId("main"),
    a = d.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].val = i;
    //adding the OnClick function to various a Tags
    addEvent(a[i], "click", (function() {
      var element = getId(ar[this.val]);

      function callBackFun(ele) {
        var strChangeHref = ar[ele];
        //change the hash URL value
        window.location.hash = strChangeHref;
      };
      var getLastVal = this.val;
      var returnVal = function() {
        callBackFun(getLastVal);
      };
      animateScroll(element, 300, returnVal);
    }), true);
  }
})();
```

```css
#left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
#left .links_ {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}
.main .ctr {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px
}
/*.main div{display: none;}*/

.main .ctr.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error cupiditate veritatis laudantium possimus quia nulla ut accusantium, dolores consectetur tempora officiis nemo similique voluptates nostrum architecto, quas qui iste sapiente.</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="left">
    <a class="links_" href="javascript:;">tab 1</a>
    <a class="links_" href="javascript:;">tab 2</a>
    <a class="links_" href="javascript:;">tab 3</a>
    <a class="links_" href="javascript:;">tab 4</a>
    <a class="links_" href="javascript:;">tab 5</a>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="ctr" id="one_">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate tenetur earum voluptate iste maxime in quod deleniti, omnis ipsam corporis atque veritatis facilis fugiat quisquam? Illum odit ratione, recusandae doloremque.</div>
    <div class="ctr" id="two_">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div>
    <div class="ctr" id="three_">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div>
    <div class="ctr" id="four_">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div>
    <div class="ctr" id="five_">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit reprehenderit, eveniet pariatur tempora deserunt nobis, asperiores odio quasi dolorem. Eius soluta ullam atque nesciunt numquam enim, vitae recusandae animi aliquid!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
added a callbackfunction to change the URL.
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77Lhbomb/1/)